# Content align when it goes over the max-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I'm struggling with this issue - i'm not sure how to achieve this type of **alignment** of content.

It should be done in the way, that with just one paragraph content is **automatically** pushed onto the **new column** when the height of it is bigger than max-height of the parent container.

I was trying to achieve it with **flexbox**, but unfortunately i wasn't able to find a good solution. Could it be done with the **pure** **CSS**? Or do i need **Javascript** for that?

Thanks, **Jakub**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this, yet?

```
div {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

It's pure CSS3, no Javascript needed. Hope it helps.

Source: [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with column count:

> -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
>
> -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
>
> column-count: 3;

```css
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-count property.</p>

<div class="newspaper">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
</div>
```

Source: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Answer (score 0):

are you working on a framework like bootstrap?
if not the blue part must have the full width of the screen so it will push all the 3 paragraphs to a new row in witch they will be aligned and under the blue title.
if it doesn't work please comment your html.